# Multiple checkboxes at jqgrid have gone uncheked after scroll with gridview: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, multipleselection

Example from http://www.trirand.net/demo/javascript/jqgrid/loading_data/scrollbar/index.html
Versions of Guriddo jqGrid JS: 4.7.0 and 4.7.1. Add `gridview: true` to repeat bug

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  $(function () {
    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid({
      url: 'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?callback=?&qwery=longorders',
      mtype: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      page: 1,
      colNames: ['Order ID', 'Customer ID', 'Order Date', 'Freight', 'Ship Name'],
      colModel: [{
        name: 'OrderID',
        key: true,
        width: 75
      }, {
        name: 'CustomerID',
        width: 150
      }, {
        name: 'OrderDate',
        width: 150
      }, {
        name: 'Freight',
        width: 150
      }, {
        name: 'ShipName',
        width: 150
      }],
      width: 750,
      height: 250,
      rowNum: 20,
      gridview: true,
      scroll: 1, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
      emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom
      pager: '#jqGridPager'
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

When you select some checkboxes on the page `X` and scroll down, and then go back to page `X`, checkboxes become unchecked, but selection is still applied, and `.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')` returns selected rows. The problem repeats only with `gridview: true`. I make some [demo screencast](http://screencast.com/t/EgAaMNsLOWp) that repeat bug.

Comment: github issue: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that it's bug in jqGrid 4.7 and free jqGrid 4.8.

I fixed the problem in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/1e6625e4a6284f409f29b65ab9f9309c9846ac12#diff-2d010088e9cda4a876dbc3e2399c83a0R2677)). [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/virtualScrollingWithMultiselect.htm) uses the current sources from github and it has no problem with the state of checkboxes in case of usage virtual scrolling.

Comment: Oleg it is good that you update free jqGrid, do you help official team vs bugs fixing?

Comment: Also will be good if you fix checked/unchecked status at the top checkbox (that check all on the page)

Comment: @AuthorProxy: I'm not sure what you mean under "official team". I posted bug fixing, many new features in jqGrid last years. After posting jqGrid 4.7 Tony changes licence (see [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). After that I started my own development by modifying the fork of jqGrid 4.7 under the name "free jqGrid". I posted recently free jqGrid 4.8 on many repositories and CDN (scroll on [the page](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) for infos) and documented it in readme and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).

Comment: @AuthorProxy: I think that virtual scrolling should be rewrote, but I have currently no time for it, so can I make small fixes in the current implementation of virtual scrolling. If you see a bug you should describe exactly the problem in [the new issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues) or in the new question on the stackoverflow.